# ESP32 Retrieve embedded binary files from the firmware .bin file

Tags: esp32, platformio, arduino-esp32, mcu

I'm using the ESP32 aWOT library to setup a webserver and I'd like to embed a bunch of binary files into the firmware .bin image (for OTA update purposes). Using PlatformIO we can use the:
`board_build.embed_txtfiles = src/file.ext`
command to embed the files to the .bin file. However I didn't figured out how to retrieve the files (either using a file system like SPIFFS or using C/assembly language). The Espressif documentation mentions the `extern const uint8_t file_ext_start[] asm("_binary_src_file_ext_start");` command to access the file content, but I didn't understand how to use it.

Supose a file.html is embedded into the .bin and then I wish to route it like 192.168.0.XX/file.html - the aWOT library provides the `app.get("/page", &handler);` in which the *handler handles the response, but how to reference the embedded html file inside the handler function?

Comment: just think about those blobs as ```char file_ext_start[] = "blah blah blah";``` and treat them accordingly (as usual strings defined in a C code) . ```embed_txtfiles``` directive  would add extra zero byte to the end of dumped file content for the file to become zero-terminated string in the code. And in case of ```embed_files``` zero terminated byte is NOT added because you know before hand that file contains arbitrary data and can contain zero byte in the middle of the data so ```strcpy```, ```strlen``` etc are not applicable to such data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following contents in your `platformio.ini` file:

```ini
[env:...]

board_build.embed_txtfiles =
    data/file1.ext
    src/file2.ext
```

You can (and must) define the following variables in your C/C++ code to access the data. The `asm(...)` part is [from ESP-IDF's documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#embedding-binary-data) and it gets the address of the data. Each one will be null-terminated because you used `embed_txtfiles` rather than `embed_files`.

```c
extern const uint8_t file_data_file1_start[] asm("_binary_data_file1_ext_start");
extern const uint8_t file_src_file2_start[] asm("_binary_src_file2_ext_start");
```

The names `file_data_file1_start` and `file_src_file2_start` can be any names, ESP-IDF's documentation just sets forth the convention that they're similar to the file paths.